# How can I Isolate the Brotherhood virus?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

How can I fix the Brotherhood of Steel virus inside the computer-lab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean [this one](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Valley_computer_virus)? There is a detailed walkthru on that page.

> The Courier must find the Virus on 3 terminals in 60 seconds to wipe it from the system. To do so, quickly enter each terminal and choose the only option you can. Then, if the text that shows up seems like a random string of letters and numbers, proceed to the next terminal. If you get a taunting message on the second screen, choose the option to isolate the virus. If you do not get all 3 terminals in the time limit, you will have to speak with Scribe Ibsen again. You will get a new 60 seconds and the terminals that the virus has infected will randomize.

Comment: Yes, but he say: "Ops, the virus jumped". And then I have to fint it again. :S

Comment: @MariusRawR " If you do not get all 3 terminals in the time limit, you will have to speak with Scribe Ibsen again. You will get a new 60 seconds and the terminals that the virus has infected will randomize."

Comment: I meant: In the 60 seconds delay, he say when its 40 seconds left for example: Oops, the virus jumped. And then I just have to find them again... Why?

Comment: Why? Because it jumped. You can do like it says on that page, and save after each jump so you can reload if you can't get it in time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple go as fast as you can an isolate at least 2 before your 10 prompt, then save. You will then be able reload until you find the location of the last terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This quest is bugged when the Science 70 option is chosen in the quest dialogue (Bug is still there in Upgrade 3). Even when the virus is partitioned off on 3 terminals, the quest doesn't register as complete. See http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Valley_computer_virus# .

I'd love it if someone who knows how to work with the G.E.C.K. would implement the fix there as a mod, so others could load it to get the quest registered as succesful. Somehow I can't get the G.E.C.K. to work successfully on my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Find 1 terminal with virus then skip 2 terminals and virus 2 will be on 3rd terminal then skip 3 and the final virus will be on 4th terminal there you have isolated all 3 and completed the task

Comment: The terminals are arranged in a grid pattern. Even if this was true (which it isn’t) how do you determine which direction to skip?